# Tab Indent in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I am writing a new line of code in Xcode 6, the tab indents across half the screen. Does anyone know how to fix this so that it is only indenting a few spaces? I have been looking around online but hadn't really found anything so I didn't know if this was a common issue, although it seems like it would be.

Comment: Have you looked at the indenting preferences already?

Comment: Xcode menu / Preferences / Text Editing / Indentation.

Comment: Hmm...whenever I start typing it will automatically indent halfway across the new line. I am not sure which of the settings in the Indenting Preferences to modify...has this ever happened to you before?